# How does minigtk.dll in XChat for Windows work?

Tags: windows, gtk

I used to write some pygtk apps for Windows, but the GTK for Windows library is always pain to maintain. I discovered XChat for Windows using a 472KB `minigtk.dll`.

Can I too use this as standard gtk alternative for pygtk and others?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

minigtk is primarily a modified form of gtk with the parts of gtk needed necessarily run XChat, however the use of the minigtk source is heavily crippled as Zed doesn't want other people to use it.

Comment: XChat has everything a useful GUI app needs. I really hope someone can make it suitable for general purpose usage. No one wants a full bloated GUI framework for simple apps.